# Unable to fetch response from the server using Retrofit2+RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using Retrofit2 and Rxjava2 to fetch data from the server but data  is not fetching from the server and is showing exception below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

**Users.php**

```
<?php

    require_once('dbconfig.php');

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $res = new stdClass();

    $row = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";

    $row_result = mysqli_query($con,$row);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($row_result) > 0){
                 
       $res->message = "User exists";
       echo json_encode($res);
     }
    else{

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`, `name`, `email`)
           VALUES ('$uid', '$name', '$email')";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   if($result){

        $res->message = "User created";
        echo json_encode($res);
   }
   else{

       $res->message = "Unable  to authenticate";
       echo json_encode($res);
    }
   
   exit();     
  }         

?>
```

Server response is :

```
{
"message": "User created"
}
```

Below is my code:

**ApiService.class**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("Users.php")
    Observable<LoginResponse> saveUser(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

**LoginResponse**

```
public class LoginResponse {

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
String message;

public LoginResponse(){

}

public LoginResponse(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

**LoginActivity.class**

```
private void saveData(){

    user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

    String uid = user.getUid();
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();

    Retrofit retrofit  = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService mapiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("userid",uid);
    jsonObject.addProperty("name",name);
    jsonObject.addProperty("email",email);

    mapiService.saveUser(jsonObject).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                             .subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {

                                     prg.dismiss();

                                     String res = loginResponse.getMessage();
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),res,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                     prg.dismiss();
                                     TastyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),
                                             TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                                     Log.d("err",e.getMessage().toString());
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onComplete() {

                                 }
                             });

}
```

Why am I getting the above exception?

Comment: Are you using HttpLoggingInterceptor, which logs request and response result?

Comment: Check if your server response start with { or "{

Comment: Its starting with `{`.I have updated post with my backend  code.Plz  take a look.

Comment: I'd recommend adding the logging interceptor and check what you're really getting.

Comment: how to add  logging interceptor please let me know.